# Video streaming via socket

Tags: android, sockets, android-mediaplayer, media, parcelfiledescriptor

I need to implement video streaming via sockets in that I have to Record video on server side and Stream it live on client side, I have connected peers via socket successfully but video stream making trouble, I am facing following problems:

1. I have tested **Media Recorder** on API level 15 and 18 but not working on higher Android version, it's giving IllegalStateException start failed -38.
2. Media Player is not working, I have tried ParcelFileDescriptor to get the stream from socket and also tried to save the stream into a file to play on Media Player but I gained no outcome.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private TextView text;
private EditText input, serverIP, port;
private Button send, connect;
private Socket socket;
private DataOutputStream outputStream;
private BufferedReader inputStream;
private String DeviceName = "Device", ipAddr;
Thread thread;
Integer portno;
private Handler handler2 = new Handler();
MediaPlayer mp;
private SurfaceView mPreview;
private SurfaceHolder holder;

VideoView mView;
SurfaceHolder mHolder;
// Video variable
MediaRecorder recorder, mMediaRecorder;
private Handler handler3 = new Handler();
boolean isRecording = false;
String AudioSavePathInDevice = null;
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd1;
Camera mCamera;

LocalServerSocket server;
LocalSocket sender;

private boolean searchNetwork() {
    log("Connecting");
    String ip = serverIP.getText().toString();
    portno = Integer.parseInt(port.getText().toString());
    try {

        socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip, portno), 100);
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        DeviceName += "1";
        Log.i("Server", DeviceName);
        log("Connected");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return false;

}

private void runNewChatServer() {
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    try {
        WifiManager wm = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        String myIP = Formatter.formatIpAddress(wm.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());

        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portno);
        log("I am ready to connect. Please enter the IP " + myIP + " in another device to connect...");
        socket = serverSocket.accept();
        DeviceName += "2";
        log("another device Connected");

        pfd1 = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
        handler3.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (isRecording) {
                    // stop recording and release camera
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                    mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                    // inform the user that recording has stopped
                    log("Stopped");
                    isRecording = false;
                } else {
                    // initialize video camera
                    if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                        // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                        // now you can start recording
                        try {
                            mMediaRecorder.start();
                            // inform the user that recording has started
                            log("Started");
                            isRecording = true;
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            log("IllegalStateException in media start " + e.getStackTrace());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            log("NullException in media start " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            log("Exception in media start " + e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                        releaseMediaRecorder();
                        // inform user
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        final String msg = e.getMessage();
        log("Oops.Connection interrupted. Please reconnect your phones." + msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textin);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textout);
    send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
    serverIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.serverip);
    port = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.port);
    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
    holder = mPreview.getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();


    mView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    mHolder = mView.getHolder();
    mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


    thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (!searchNetwork()) {
                    runNewChatServer();
                }
                else
                {
                    prepareMediaPlayer();
                }

                outputStream = new DataOutputStream(
                        socket.getOutputStream());
                inputStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        socket.getInputStream()));
                while (true) {
                    String Message = inputStream.readLine();
                    if (Message != null) {
                        log(Message);
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                log("Error: IO Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log("Error: Exception");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (outputStream == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                String Message = input.getText().toString() + "\n";
                outputStream.write(Message.getBytes());
                log2(input.getText().toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            input.setText("");
        }
    });

    connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            ipAddr = serverIP.getText().toString();
            thread.start();
        }
    });


}

private void log(final String message) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        String DeviceName2 = "";

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (DeviceName.equals("Device1")) {
                DeviceName2 = "Device2";
            } else if (DeviceName.equals("Device2")) {
                DeviceName2 = "Device1";
            } else {
                DeviceName2 = "UnknowDevice";
            }

            text.setText(text.getText() + "\n" + DeviceName2 + " :"
                    + message);

        }
    });
}
private void log2(final String message) {
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            text.setText(text.getText() + "\n" + "you" + " :"
                    + message);

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));


    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(pfd1.getFileDescriptor());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        log("IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log("IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean prepareMediaPlayer() {

    try {
        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.fromSocket(socket);
        pfd.getFileDescriptor().sync();
        mp.setDataSource(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
        pfd.close();
        mp.setDisplay(mHolder);
        mp.prepareAsync();
        mp.start();

        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("CameraInstance", e.getMessage());
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaRecorder();       // if you are using MediaRecorder, release it first
    releaseCamera();              // release the camera immediately on pause event
}

private void releaseMediaRecorder(){
    if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
        mMediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
        mMediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
        mMediaRecorder = null;
        mCamera.lock();           // lock camera for later use
    }
}

private void releaseCamera(){
    if (mCamera != null){
        mCamera.release();        // release the camera for other applications
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

   /* try {
        prepareVideoRecorder();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log("IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder2: " + e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }*/
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                           int height) {
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (isRecording) {
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        isRecording = false;
    }
    releaseMediaRecorder();
    releaseCamera();
    finish();
}
}
```

I have also used these following code snippet to save the input stream into a file to play on Media Player but it didn't work for me.

```
File downloadingMediaFile = File.createTempFile("downloading", ".mp4");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);
IOUtils.copy(socket.getInputStream(), out);
mp.setDataSource(out.getFD());
```

I have tried this code snippet to Record the video stream on Lollipop or Higher API version but it's too didn't work.

```
ParcelFileDescriptor[] parcelFileDescriptors = new ParcelFileDescriptor[0];
try {
parcelFileDescriptors = ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe();
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelRead = new 
ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[0]);
ParcelFileDescriptor parcelWrite  = new 
ParcelFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptors[1]);
mMediarecorder.setOutputFile(parcelWrite.fromSocket(socket).getFileDescriptor());
```

Comment: If you're recording the video on server side, why do you need `MediaRecorder`? If you're just streaming on android you could just use a `VideoView`. No ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: thanks for correcting halfer

Comment: vlatkozelka how will this work? Can you please give some demo code...

Comment: If you wish to draw attention to your comment Iqra, you need to use the right syntax i.e. @vlatkozelka.